# Why I can`t get array length

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help with array length.

I tried using Object.keys

```js
{  
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('volagas.sharepoint.com')/sites('volagas.sharepoint.com%2C9a51e995-62f9-4b40-81c2-d167c4c79182%2C2646bdf6-214f-482c-826f-c5e21676a79c')/lists('84885DBF-980E-4AD2-8377-AAB746E6D41A')/items",
   "value":[  
      {  
         "@odata.etag":"\"dfd2e718-5cac-4d7a-b8b3-7dba435dae29,3\"",
         "createdDateTime":"2018-11-26T11:03:29Z",
         "eTag":"\"dfd2e718-5cac-4d7a-b8b3-7dba435dae29,3\"",
         "id":"1",
         "lastModifiedDateTime":"2018-11-27T10:40:11Z",
         "webUrl":"https://volagas.sharepoint.com/doc/Lists/List60/1_.000",
         "createdBy":{  
            "user":{  
               "email":"d.kalinin@volgagas.com",
               "id":"1606566d-042b-4761-8229-ddd3a4e4a8b9",
               "displayName":"Данил Калинин"
            }
         },
         "lastModifiedBy":{  
            "user":{  
               "email":"d.kalinin@volgagas.com",
               "id":"1606566d-042b-4761-8229-ddd3a4e4a8b9",
               "displayName":"Данил Калинин"
            }
         },
         "parentReference":{  

         },
         "contentType":{  
            "id":"0x01004865A45A1D8A8C4FA163CEB418DD12E6"
         },
         "fields@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('volagas.sharepoint.com')/sites('volagas.sharepoint.com%2C9a51e995-62f9-4b40-81c2-d167c4c79182%2C2646bdf6-214f-482c-826f-c5e21676a79c')/lists('84885DBF-980E-4AD2-8377-AAB746E6D41A')/items('1')/fields/$entity",
         "fields":{  
            "@odata.etag":"\"dfd2e718-5cac-4d7a-b8b3-7dba435dae29,3\"",
            "Title":"тест_1_edited",
            "LinkTitleNoMenu":"тест_1_edited",
            "LinkTitle":"тест_1_edited",
            "ShipmentDateTime":"2018-11-29T21:00:00Z",
            "Good":"Нефть",
            "PricePerTon@odata.type":"#Single",
            "PricePerTon":5000,
            "Contractor":"TESTCONTRACTOR_1",
            "CarNumber":"TESTCONTRACTOR_1",
            "TankNumber":"TESTCONTRACTOR_1",
            "DriverName":"TESTCONTRACTOR_1",
            "Status":"Свободно",
            "_x0421__x0447__x0435__x0442_":"Выслать счет",
            "Payment":false,
            "id":"1",
            "ContentType":"Элемент",
            "Modified":"2018-11-27T10:40:11Z",
            "Created":"2018-11-26T11:03:29Z",
            "AuthorLookupId":"2211",
            "EditorLookupId":"2211",
            "_UIVersionString":"1.0",
            "Attachments":false,
            "Edit":"",
            "ItemChildCount":"0",
            "FolderChildCount":"0",
            "_ComplianceFlags":"",
            "_ComplianceTag":"",
            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime":"",
            "_ComplianceTagUserId":""
         }
      },
      {  
         "@odata.etag":"\"4c72729b-d43a-47c5-acab-0a5e9a9f64f8,3\"",
         "createdDateTime":"2018-11-27T06:18:51Z",
         "eTag":"\"4c72729b-d43a-47c5-acab-0a5e9a9f64f8,3\"",
         "id":"2",
         "lastModifiedDateTime":"2018-11-27T10:40:20Z",
         "webUrl":"https://volagas.sharepoint.com/doc/Lists/List60/2_.000",
         "createdBy":{  
            "user":{  
               "email":"d.kalinin@volgagas.com",
               "id":"1606566d-042b-4761-8229-ddd3a4e4a8b9",
               "displayName":"Данил Калинин"
            }
         },
         "lastModifiedBy":{  
            "user":{  
               "email":"d.kalinin@volgagas.com",
               "id":"1606566d-042b-4761-8229-ddd3a4e4a8b9",
               "displayName":"Данил Калинин"
            }
         },
         "parentReference":{  

         },
         "contentType":{  
            "id":"0x01004865A45A1D8A8C4FA163CEB418DD12E6"
         },
         "fields@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('volagas.sharepoint.com')/sites('volagas.sharepoint.com%2C9a51e995-62f9-4b40-81c2-d167c4c79182%2C2646bdf6-214f-482c-826f-c5e21676a79c')/lists('84885DBF-980E-4AD2-8377-AAB746E6D41A')/items('2')/fields/$entity",
         "fields":{  
            "@odata.etag":"\"4c72729b-d43a-47c5-acab-0a5e9a9f64f8,3\"",
            "Title":"тест_2",
            "LinkTitleNoMenu":"тест_2",
            "LinkTitle":"тест_2",
            "ShipmentDateTime":"2018-12-01T21:00:00Z",
            "Good":"ГК",
            "PricePerTon@odata.type":"#Single",
            "PricePerTon":10000,
            "Contractor":"CONTRACTOR2",
            "CarNumber":"У152КХ",
            "TankNumber":"Б554ЕН",
            "DriverName":"Иванов Иван Иванович",
            "Status":"Свободно",
            "_x0421__x0447__x0435__x0442_":"Выслать счет",
            "Payment":true,
            "id":"2",
            "ContentType":"Элемент",
            "Modified":"2018-11-27T10:40:20Z",
            "Created":"2018-11-27T06:18:51Z",
            "AuthorLookupId":"2211",
            "EditorLookupId":"2211",
            "_UIVersionString":"1.0",
            "Attachments":false,
            "Edit":"",
            "ItemChildCount":"0",
            "FolderChildCount":"0",
            "_ComplianceFlags":"",
            "_ComplianceTag":"",
            "_ComplianceTagWrittenTime":"",
            "_ComplianceTagUserId":""
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

why I cant get `value.lenght`?

There is an assumption that it is because of the quotes. In that case all the same a question - how to correct it?

It doesn't parse

I tried using `Object.keys`

What are your ideas about this?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here, or what the question is

Comment: have you spelt length correct because you keep spelling it wrong in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is an `Object` and not an `array`.

Get the `length` of the root of your `object`.

```
var length_object = Object.keys(your_object).length;
```

Get the `length` of your 'values'

```
var length_values = your_object['value'].length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assigning this object to a `variable` solved the issue. Setting it to:

```
var obj = { /* your object here */ }
console.log(obj.value.length) // returns 2
```

Because the way it is presented in your question, you did not assign that object to anything, hence you can not access the property of `value` and its `length`